# Do not insert null values in Mysqli Query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an array of field in my form

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="event_title[]">
```

I am getting all the data and inserted in my database successfully

```
    $events = $_POST['event_title'];
    $totalEvents = sizeof($events);
    for($i = 0; $i < $totalEvents; $i++) {
      $event_title = $events[$i];
      $sql1 = "INSERT INTO event_title (event_id, event_title) 
            VALUES (
            '".$lastid."',
            '".$event_title."'
            )";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
```

My problem is how do I prevent NULL values inserted in my database?

Comment: check if the variable is null. if($variable != null) { // insert it} else{ // it is null, throw exception}

Comment: Could also change your database table schema/columns to `NOT NULL`

Comment: With your code it's impossible to insert NULL values in database.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if variable is empty can use !=''

```
  $events = $_POST['event_title'];
        $totalEvents = sizeof($events);
        for($i = 0; $i < $totalEvents; $i++) {
          $event_title = $events[$i];
          if($event_title!=''){
          $sql1 = "INSERT INTO event_title (event_id, event_title) 
                VALUES (
                '".$lastid."',
                '".$event_title."'
                )";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
       }
    }
```

Comment: why couldn't you use if($event_title != null)

Comment: is there a big different?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  `NOT NULL` constraint in creating or modifying the table.

If you haven't already create you table:

```
CREATE TABLE authors(
  author_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  author_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  bio VARCHAR(400) NULL
)
```

You can add `NOT NULL` constraint to you column to prevent `NULL` values.

If you already have created your table, you can modify:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ALTER COLUMN column NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$totalEvents = sizeof($_POST['event_title']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalEvents; $i++) {
    $event_title = $events[$i];
    if (strlen($event_title) == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO event_title (event_id, event_title) 
    VALUES (
    '" . $lastid . "',
    '" . $event_title . "'
    )";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll clear up a common misconception.

NULL doesn't mean the same as FALSE, or an empty string or 0. It's NULL. It essentially means 'UNKNOWN'.

A NOT NULL string field can have an empty value but it cannot have a NULL value (ie it can be known to be an empty string but cannot be unknown)

As to your question. Your form validation should pick up if any fields haven't been set long before you get to the point where you're trying to insert anything into the database.

Here's the workflow in pseudocode:

```
DO {

 GET form submission.

WHILE (form is not valid);

insert form values into database.
```

If the rule is that your table doesn't allow NULLs - check those columns aren't null as part of the validation and fail the validation if they are.